# Is typing/pressing a key is the same as programming?

Tags: compile

Is typing/pressing a key is the same as programming?

e.g. When programming in C++, it first go to the first level of [Programming hierarchy](http://blog.malwarebytes.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/FlowDiagram2.png) - `High-Level Language` down to `Assembly language > Machine language > etc.`

If a single key is pressed will it also go through that process?

Comment: I would say it is necessary, but not sufficient condition. Therefore, pressing a single key doesn't count as programming.

Comment: it will sent directly to Machine language and pass the other?

Comment: Pressing a key have an effect on the computer,  but it doesn't generate new code at whichever level,  which is the meaning of program WRITEing.

Comment: *Is typing/pressing a key the same as writing an essay or novel?*  Of course not.  Programming is *writing* programs.

Answer (score 1):

[Programming hierarchy](http://blog.malwarebytes.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/FlowDiagram2.png) is not work in same way as network stack layers hierarchy.

TLDR Absolutely no.

When program on pure compiling language is compiled, binary representation built and only that binary representation executing. And binary representation ,in common case, have no sign from which high level language and from which instructions it compiled.

Assembler is mostly human readable representation of binary code.

It why we know disassembling, but not decplusplusing and so one ...

If we program on Java or Python program not translated to C or C++ at first (but You can find sometimes translator from some language to C or C++) it compiled into some intermediate binary representation - bytecode that is interpreted (may be indirect execution more appropriate term in case of bytecode) or JIT compiled into native binary code.